# Reduced Equivariant Cohomology

Tags: equivariant-cohomology

I read an article stating that if a finite group $G$ acts on a compact and path connected topological space $M$ and the action has a fixed point $x_0$, then
$$
H^p_G(M;\mathbb{Z})\simeq H^p_G(x_0;\mathbb{Z})\oplus \widetilde{H}^p_G(M;\mathbb{Z})\qquad\forall p\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
where $H^p_G(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is the Equivariant Cohomology group of $M$ and it is written that $\widetilde{H}^p_G(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is the reduced cohomology group. Since
$$
H^p_G(x_0;\mathbb{Z})\simeq H_{\text{group}}^p(G;\mathbb{Z}),
$$
and for certain groups, such as cyclic and dihedral groups,  $H_{\text{group}}^p(G;\mathbb{Z})$ can be different from zero also for $p>0$,  it seems that the definition of reduced cohomology in equivariant cohomology may differ from the definition given in classical cohomology (where $H^p(M;\mathbb{Z})=\widetilde{H}^p(M;\mathbb{Z})$ for $p>0$). Based on equation (1), it seems that  $\widetilde{H}^p_G(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is the cokernel of the map
$$
H^p_G(x_0;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^p_G(M;\mathbb{Z})
$$
induced by the constant map $M\rightarrow x_0$. Is this understanding correct? If so, why is there a different definition of reduced cohomology in equivariant cohomology? Can you provide any references on this topic? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which article did you read?

Comment: @feynhat this is the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.09194 . Proposition 3.10